# Select ID of a row with max value

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

How can I select the ID of a row with the max value of another column in a query that joins multiple tables?

For example, say I have three tables. `tblAccount` which stores a grouping of users, like a family. `tblUser` which stores the users, each tied to a record from `tblAccount`. And each user can be part of a plan, stored in `tblPlans`. Each plan has a `Rank` column that determines it's sorting when comparing the levels of plans. For example, Lite is lower than Premium. So the idea is that each user can have a separate plan, like Premium, Basic, Lite etc..., but the parent account does not have a plan.

How can I determine the highest plan in the account with a single query?

`tblAccount`

| PKID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Adams Family |
| 2 | Cool Family |

`tblUsers`

| PKID | Name | AccountID | PlanID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | Phil | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | Suzie | 2 | 1 |

`tblPlans`

| PKID | Name | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Premium | 3 |
| 2 | Basic | 2 |
| 3 | Elite | 4 |
| 4 | Lite | 1 |

Here's the result I'm hoping to produce:

| AccountID | Name | HighestPlanID | PlanName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Adams Family | 1 | Premium |

I've tried:

```
SELECT U.AccountID, A.Name, MAX(P.Rank) AS Rank, P.PKID as HighestPlanID, P.Name as PlanName
FROM tblPlans P
INNER JOIN tblUsers U ON U.PlanID = P.PKID
INNER JOIN tblAccounts A ON U.AccountID = A.PKID
WHERE U.AccountID = 2
```

and the query will not always work, selecting the MAX of Rank does not select entire row's values from tblPlans.

*I am looking for a solution that is compatible with `mysql-5.6.10`*

Comment: @bill-karwin - After reviewing `Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL`, I believe my question is a bit different in that it involves multiple tables. The answers in the linked question explain joining on the same table, which I cannot do here

Comment: I have reopened the question, but I suggest that the technique is the same even for joined tables. Follow the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag, this general type of question has been asked many times, and there is undoubtedly a case involving joined tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables and use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the row you want. Then filtering is ieasy.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select a.*, p.*,
    row_number() over(partition by a.pkid order by p.rank desc) as rn
  from tblaccount a
  join tblusers u on u.accountid = a.pkid
  join tblplans p on p.pkid = u.planid
) x
where rn = 1
```

Inside the subquery you can add `where u.accountid = 2` to retrieve a single account of interest, instead of all of them.

Comment: Ah shoot - I should have mentioned I am using `mysql-5.6.10`. `partition by` and `row_number` is not available for the version I am using

Comment: Aha! I took your answer and reworked it slightly, most credit to you :D

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @the-impaler, I massaged their answer a bit and came out with something very similar:

```
select *
from (
  select a.*, p.*
  from tblaccount a
  join tblusers u on u.accountid = a.pkid
  join tblplans p on p.pkid = u.planid
  where u.accountid = 2
  order by p.rank desc
) x limit 1
```

The subquery sorts each user by plan rank from top to bottom, and then the top level query selects the top most row with `limit 1`. It seems to work!